# Necessity of using modules in proof that direct limits are exact

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

I recently read the proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121122/why-do-direct-limits-preserve-exactness) that direct limits are exact functors in the category of $R$-modules. In that proof, I don't see where Arturo is using the fact that we are working in a category of modules, but in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123552/exactness-of-direct-limit-of-other-than-modules) we get an example showing that taking direct limits is not necessarily exact in an arbitrary category.

**So where are we using that we work in a category of modules in the proof that direct limits are exact functors?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many of the arguments in Arturo's proof use elements. Some can likely be removed, e.g. the ones in the proof that the composition is $0$, but I don't see how to remove the $k$ from the line

> so by exactness of the original diagram we know that there exists $k \in K_i$...

Comment: I see. So would it be fair to say that the proof should work in any abelian category whose objects are sets?

Comment: That is a vague question. If I were feeling generous I would point out that if the forgetful functor preserves direct limits (= filtered colimits) and finite limits and is conservative then the answer is yes. If I were feeling malicious I would say that any concretisable abelian category not satisfying AB5 is a counterexample.